# What is negative Latency?

Tags: server, data-science, latency

**What is Latency ?**

> Latency is the delay between a user's action and a application's
> response to that action

With these knowledge Negative Latency seems non-sense and impossible,
*But after thinking different possibilities, I came up with this*

> with an AI that can predict a move far enough into the future,
> negative ping might be possible

**So, Is Negative Latency actually possible or I am just Hallucinating ?**

Comment: Google's Stadia Platform does use the term _negative latency_. An introductive overview can be found in this blog post: https://nolannicholson.com/2019/12/16/exploring-negative-latency.html

Comment: Why do you want to know? Did you find the term "negative latency" somewhere, and if so, where did you find it? Or did you just come up with it yourself and do you merely want to satisfy idle curiosity?

Comment: I am a Discord Bot Developer, and using Heroku for Hosting which is giving 15ms Latency... so, I just Randomly Thought about Negative Latency

Comment: Do read my updated answer regarding your latest comment. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have `3 apples`, and I ask you to give me `5 apples`, will you be able to? The best you can do is give me the 3 apples that you have. Not every quantity belongs to the set of real numbers, some are restricted to whole numbers. Latency is one such thing. As a random variable, it can only take values between 0 to +ve infinity like apples.

Regarding what you have mentioned, Google already uses AI-based algorithms for what they **label** as `negative latency` (emphasis on the word - label)

> Google’s homegrown streaming tech, which we first saw as “Project Stream” alongside Stadia, will include something called “negative latency,” which sounds impressive. In practice, it’s all a means to eliminate the frustrations that come with lag. The plan is to run games at a high FPS (frames per second) rate, which sounds counterintuitive to lag, but it helps on the user’s end. If Stadia servers detect lag because of a wonky connection, increasing the framerate reduces the risk of a game visibly stalling. More frames coming down the pipe means less risk of stutter. [Source](https://insights.dice.com/2019/10/21/google-stadia-negative-latency/)

So `negative latency` doesn't really mean that literally. It just means that they use some algorithm to reduce stuttering in FPS due to lag/bad connection by boosting the frame rate when it detects a wonky connection at the user's end. So maybe the right word for it is, `latency reduction` or `negate latency`

**Know the difference between business jargon that generates hype and true labels that describe the actual innovation.**

---

> I am a Discord Bot Developer, and using Heroku for Hosting which is giving 15ms Latency... so, I just Randomly Thought about Negative Latency

Imagine some information being passed from A to B. Let's say this is a chat between A and B. A sends `hello` and it reaches B `15 ms` later.  To do what google has done with `negative latency`, I need to predict what B will respond to A, and send it to A faster than they can think and type it. And this is not possible.

What google stadia does is that it predicts user in-game actions and creates predicted frames for that. These frames can now be used to given the illusion of a seamless lag-less experience (at least as they claim it)

Comment: In short, it's just a specious pseudo-intellectual BS marking term, hoping most people won't question it.